# Function to Comment Multiple Lines Vimrc

Tags: vim, comments

So I currently like this solution to commenting multiple lines in vim:

1. Press `CTRL-v` (to go into Visual Block mode)
2. Select the lines you want to comment
3. Press `Shift-i` (to go into Insert mode)
4. Type whatever comment characters your language uses
5. Press `ESC ESC` (pressing the escape key twice makes the results appear faster)

But I would like some help mapping these steps into my vimrc file.
I currently use the following to comment lines out:

```
vnoremap ;/ <C-v>0I// <ESC>
```

For those who want an explanation of what the command does:

You basically type `;/` when you're in Visual mode to use this (Visual, Visual Line, and Visual Block mode all work since the `<C-v>` part forces you into Visual Block mode, which is correct).

The `0I` part will put you in Insert mode at the beginning of the line.

The `// <ESC>` part will insert the comment characters `//` and put you back into Normal mode.

The part I need help with is uncommenting the lines. How do I write a function in my vimrc that will basically let me toggle the `//` characters?

Ideally, the solution would involve the following:

1. Selecting the lines
2. Pressing `;/`
3. If there are NO `//` characters then it will insert them
4. If there ARE `//` characters then it will remove them

Comment: We have http://vi.stackexchange.com/ . You probably should be using one function for commenting and another for uncommenting, then allow for ranges to not need <C-v>.

Comment: `0I` ? `I` is enough for inserting at the beginning of the line !

Comment: Oh cool. I didn't know about vi.stachexchange.  I personally like having just the one function so that you only have to remember one command. I also prefer using a visual select over using ranges

Comment: Also check out [tyru/caw.vim](https://github.com/tyru/caw.vim).

Comment: `0I`? It's either `0i` or `I`. Also, writing a commenting function is the most common first step in vimscript. I suggest using a plugin instead, like commentary by Tim Pope.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Put this in your `.vimrc` file:

```
vnoremap <silent> ;/ :call ToggleComment()<cr>

function! ToggleComment()
        if matchstr(getline(line(".")),'^\s*\/\/.*$') == ''
                :execute "s:^://:"
        else
                :execute "s:^\s*//::"
        endif
endfunction
```

Comment: It works perfectly, but can you explain how this works? @Meninx

Comment: it checks every line if there is // at the beginning via matchstr function.if Yes it makes a substitution by deleting otherwise adding them. (excuse my brevity -mobile-) is it ok ?

Answer (score 0):

check the Commentary plugin. It allows to have one binding for all languages.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty easy with python script

```
function! Comment()
python3 << EOF
import vim
r = vim.current.range
line = vim.current.buffer[r.start]
if line.startswith('// '):
    vim.current.buffer[r.start] = vim.current.buffer[r.start].replace('// ', '')
else:
    vim.current.buffer[r.start] = '// ' + vim.current.buffer[r.start]
EOF
endfunction

" ctrl slash
noremap <C-_> :call Comment()<CR>
```