# Commenting a line of a tcl file in GVIM

Tags: vim

In Gvim, I want to comment the lines in a tcl file which has the following pattern:

```
 -EnableCustomPfc "FALSE" \
```

I could append a # in the beginning of the line by doing:

```
 :%s/-EnableCustomPfc/#&/
```

But how do I append another # at the end of line to comment only this particular line?

Answer (score 1):

Try this command for lines containing `-EnableCustomPfc`:

```
:g/-EnableCustomPfc/ s/^.*$/#&#/
```

or if you want the whole pattern (**i.e.** lines containing `-EnableCustomPfc "FALSE" \` literally):

```
:g/-EnableCustomPfc "FALSE" \\/ s/^.*$/#&#/
```

Comment: Excellent way to do it, however the anchors are superfluous.

Comment: You are **totally right** but for clarity it is worth noting it.

Comment: Certainly, although it is a relative matter and for me personally removing what is superfluous improves clarity. Another "descriptive" way is `s/^|$/#/g`

Comment: In your "descriptive" you mean `s/\v^|$/#/g`  for more clarity ;). +1

Comment: Precisely, depending on magic options `\v` or `\|` is needed. But who has very magic disabled anyway? :D You got it, just leaving here as more ideas to the OP.

Comment: This might be useful if you'd like to have a permanent method of commenting lines. By making this entry in my _vimrc(gvim) file, I'm able to comment a line by pressing #.    `nnoremap # 0i#<Esc>$a#<Esc>`

Comment: I would suggest **[this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38669419/4392605)** for commenting lines as you can toggle them off/on.